# Swagger @Schema with Groovy: How do I generate an array type?

Tags: groovy, swagger

Hi I am using Core Swagger to generate a Swagger YML file from a Groovy class but struggling to see what type in Groovy generates an array data type : [https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array][1]

My Groovy class is as below:

```
       import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema

       @Schema
    class simpleClass{
        String[] strArray3 = new String[3];
        def mixed =   ["foo", 5, -2, "bar"]
        def names = ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"]
        String[] strArray= ["lucas", "Fred", "Mary"]
        Integer[] intArray= new Integer[3];
    }
```

But when I gradle build the Swagger.yml doesn't have the array type:

```
    components:
      schemas:
        Object:
          type: object
        $simpleClass:
          type: object
          properties:
            strArray3:
              type: string
            mixed:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Object'
            names:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Object'
            strArray:
              type: string
            intArray:
              type: integer
              format: int32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question.

I found a solution to declare the array as below in my Groovy class, hopefully it is of use to someone. Thanks.

```
 ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```